# CommunicationsException while connecting to MySQL database via JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am using Spring and I have a interface in which all the database details are stored as well as a `Login.java` which implements the interface to get the database details. When I use the line below for connection it works fine

```
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

However if I use the line below, I get the error: "`The exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`"

```
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+dbIP+":3306/"+dbName, dbUsername, dbPassword);
```

Contents of the interface file

```
     public interface DBProvider {
         final String  dbUsername = "root";
         final String  dbPassword = "admin";
         final String tblUsers = "tbl_users";
         final String dbName = "mydatabase";
         final String dbIP = "1.1.1.1"; //example
     }
```

What should I change to fetch the IP from the interface file and establish a successful SQL connection?

Comment: Check whether the IP and it´s port is accessible from your machine or from where you are trying to connect the database? It may be the port is not accessible from your machine or where you are trying to deploy your code on tomcat or any other application server.

Comment: most probably a network issue. Check you have access to the database host machine

Comment: Database and the application are in the same machine

Comment: if database and application both are on same machine then use 127.0.0.1

Comment: ok..it works fine when I use 127.0.0.1     Why am I not able to use the IP of the machine in which both the database and application are running?

Comment: Likely because the MySQL installation is to listening on 127.0.0.1 only; they simply cannot accept connection to another IP-address (even if the request originates from the same machine).

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities.  MySQL is only binding to 127.0.0.1 (as Mark mentioned) or the MySQL user is only allowed to connect from localhost or the server's firewall treats traffic toward the public IP differently.